# How can I specify the description for the MariaDB windows service?

Tags: mysql, windows, mariadb

When I install MariaDB 5.5.32 as a Windows service using the instructions from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html):

```
mysqld --install MySQL123
```

the windows service that's being created has no description:

```
> sc qdescription MySQL123
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: MySQL123
DESCRIPTION:
```

I couldn't find any command line option to specify the Description for the service.

Comment: Open the windows service manager and add a description there manually.

Comment: This is part of a script, I need command line solution.

Comment: @ Norbert: You removed the "MySQL" tags and replaced with "Windows". This is not a Windows question. The service is installed through mysqld and I expect it to support all typical configuration of a service. Makes sense?

Comment: The service part is MS Windows, in my opinion completely not related to mysql, mariadb or any other application.

Comment: Googled how to set the service description from the command line:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssehgal/archive/2009/06/01/configuring-windows-services-using-command-prompt.aspx. Might depend on your windows version. With this you can update the install script of mysql or run it as after script.

Comment: I was also looking for a confirmation that this is not possible the normal way. Thanks for your involvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc description "MySQL123" "Your description here."
```

[see Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742069(v=ws.11).aspx)